# xamarin forms cultureinfo exception name cannot be null when renderer is added

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, cultureinfo

I have a problem with my Xamarin forms project.
the app is working fine i but as soon as I add the hybridwebviewrenderer i get an cultureinfoexception error public token name cannot be null.
The error dissappears if i comment the [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))] line.
Any idea why this happens?

[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly potthål, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.dll
**System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException:** 'Culture name neutral, PublicKeyToken=null is not supported.
Parameter name: name'

followed microsoft learns example.
if i donwload an example it works fine but as soon aas i add the renderer and classes to my project I get the error.

```
    const string JavascriptFunction = @"
        function invokeCSharpAction(data)
        {
            jsBridge.invokeAction(data);
        }

        function testFunction(data)
        {
            console.log('funkar hit');
            jsBridge.invokeTest(data);
        }";

    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");

            string a = ((HybridWebView)Element).Uri;
            Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{((HybridWebView)Element).Uri}");

        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: A [CultureNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.culturenotfoundexception?view=net-7.0) exception was thrown whenever the construction of an invalid culture was eventually attempted within a method. I tried to reproduce the situation you described but failed. Could you please provide the full code of your custom render ? In addition, commenting out [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))] means not calling this part of the code, so the error disappears.

Comment: I also created a new Xamarin forms mobile project and there the renderer works fine

Comment: Does the previous error (CultureNotFoundException) still occur?

Comment: if i add the renderer to that project it does. i ahev added it multiple times dont understand why.
but when i add a new proejct to the solution it works everytime.

Comment: Creating a new project and then copying the files to the new project is also a way to solve the problem. You can try to copy the code from the previous project to the new project.

Comment: I have done that now.
but it is annoying to not know what is causing it. Thanks for your time :)